# AJAX loading my php page is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have code to load my bookmark.php via AJAX when clicking submit but when I'm clicking it alert was popping up but bookmark.php is not working properly.
Here is my code in below: 
What am I missing ?

PHP:

```
require_once 'class.trip.php';

$trip = new TRIP();
$save = $trip->saveTrip();
```

HTML/AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $('#joinform').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'bookmark.php',
        data: $('#joinform').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          alert('form was submitted');
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<form id="joinform">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Join This Trip"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: You want to load bookmark using ajax ?

Comment: How does your class.trip.php look like?

Comment: @leopard Yes indeed

Comment: @lisectech public function saveTrip()
 {
  try
  {
   
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO trip_user(status) 
                                                 VALUES(:status)");
              
   $stmt->bindvalue(":status", 'bookmark');
               
    
   $stmt->execute(); 
   
   return $stmt; 
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   echo $e->getMessage();
  }    
 }

Comment: @lisectech bookmark.php is working fine

Comment: And you are posting the page not loading the page. You should use `type:'get` and append the html of returned page in some div.

Comment: @MartneyAcha so what is wrong? What would you like the code to do, apart form displaying the alert? You are using the `POST` method and it's for posting data, not getting it.

Comment: @lisatech I would want to send my data sand save it using bookmark.php, but when im trying to send data to bookmark.php it doesnt work. I would jsut like to test if bookmark.php is working to save my data.

Comment: @MartneyAcha your code is not even getting data from `$_POST` so there is no way it could save data from the form into your database. Please read about it here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @lisectech I already found the problem, its in the URL.